# Adding new entity to database gives "IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF" error

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, .net-core, automapper

I create a new domain entity, map it to persistence entity and save it to database. This gives me an sql error, like this.

> SqlException: Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'DefaultPageContent' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF

I have checked Identity on the table and it is true, I have checked the designer and identity is true for all tables, like this:

```
modelBuilder.Entity("Namespace.Models.PageContent", b =>
    {
        b.Property<int>("IdPageContent")
            .ValueGeneratedOnAdd()
            .HasAnnotation("SqlServer:ValueGenerationStrategy", SqlServerValueGenerationStrategy.IdentityColumn);
    });
```

I have also tried adding

```
[DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
```

to the Id property on both the Domain and Persistence models, and separately..

Here the Pagecontent is created if it does not exist in database.

```
private async Task UpdateCustomerPageContent(UpdateCustomerPageContentCommand request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    var customerPage = await _unitOfWork.CustomerPages.FindById(request.CustomerPageId);
    var content =
        customerPage.PageContent.FirstOrDefault(x => x.IdOrganization.Equals(request.CustomerOrganizationId));
    var settings =
        customerPage.CustomerPageSettings.First(x => x.IdOrganization.Equals(request.CustomerOrganizationId));
    settings.UseDefaultContent = false;
    if (content == null)
    {
        content = new Domain.PageContent();
        content.IdOrganization = request.CustomerOrganizationId;
        content.LastUpdatedBy = "noname"; //TODO: Getfrom UPN Claim
        content.CustomerPage = customerPage;
    }

    content.HtmlContent = request.HtmlString;
    await _unitOfWork.PageContent.InsertOrUpdate(content, cancellationToken);
    await _unitOfWork.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken);
}
```

This is the insertOrupdate method where the mapping is also happening.

```
public async Task InsertOrUpdate(Domain.PageContent pageContent, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
{
    var entity = _mapper.Map<Models.PageContent>(pageContent);
    if (pageContent.IdPageContent == default)
    {
        await _context.PageContent.AddAsync(entity, cancellationToken);
    }
    else
    {
        _context.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
    }
}
```

This is the domain model (in this case the persistence model is exactly the same)

```
public class PageContent
{
    public int IdPageContent { get; set; }
    public long IdOrganization { get; set; }
    public string HtmlContent { get; set; }
    public string LastUpdatedBy { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime UpdatedDate { get; set; }

    public CustomerPage CustomerPage { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the simple mapping configuration considering everything is the same

```
public PageContentProfile()
{
    CreateMap<Models.PageContent, Domain.PageContent>();
    CreateMap<Domain.PageContent, Models.PageContent>();
}
```

Because identity is true, creating and adding a new entity should not give an error. The Id on both models is '0' if that means something..

Comment: Exceptions mentions table `DefaultPageContent`. Is it place where `PageContent` are stored or is it different Entity?

Comment: its is the same place, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: If you set breakpoint to here: `if (pageContent.IdPageContent == default)` is `entity.IdPageContent` also 0 here?

Answer (score 1):

i know this question is old,
but for the ones wh are still looking
you may try two solutions

1- check if the entity is getting inserted twice, sometimes it happens from the outer function that is calling the insert, especially if it was in a loop.

2- in the question, there is the section

```
    if (content == null)
{
    content = new Domain.PageContent();
    content.IdOrganization = request.CustomerOrganizationId;
    content.LastUpdatedBy = "noname"; //TODO: Getfrom UPN Claim
    content.CustomerPage = customerPage;
}
```

i've faced an issue before when i linked two objects together like the line here

```
content.CustomerPage = customerPage;
```

it seemed like that entity framework considered this link as a new object getting inserted too as well, and threw an exception, try to link them using the object id
like this:

```
content.CustomerPageId = customerPage.Id;
```

or reverse the link between the two objects like this

```
customerPage.PageContent.Add(content);
```

and update the customerPage itself as it seems to be the parent object from the issue provided.